# Yesod/Persistent one-to-one query

Tags: haskell, yesod

Say, in Yesod/Persistent, I have models setup like so:

```
User
    ident Text
    password Text Maybe
    UniqueUser ident
Question
    title Text
    asker UserId Eq
```

And I have a list of `Question`s, and would like to retrieve the corresponding list of `User`s. How would I go about doing this?

I've thought about joins, but those are one-to-many, not one-to-one (I suppose it doesn't matter, but I'd like a simpler solution). Manually doing the join is also an option, but I'm worried about performance - I have

```
questions <- runDB $ selectList [QuestionTitle !=. ""] [LimitTo 10]
let askerIds = map (\(Entity _ q) -> questionAsker q) questions
askers <- sequence $ map (runDB . get) askerIds
let questionsAndAskers = zip questions askers
```

but I'm worried about using `runDB` in the `map` (wouldn't it make a separate request to the database for each user?)

Is there a better/more idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes I think it's fair to assume that every time you hit `runDB`, another database query will be performed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't type-checked this yet, but I would stick the whole thing inside of `runDB`:

```
runDB $ selectList [QuestionTitle !=. ""] [LimitTo 10] >>= mapM (\qe@(Entity _ q) -> do
    asker <- get $ questionAsker q
    return (qe, asker))
```

Comment: So with persistent there will be N+1 selects instead of 1?

Comment: Yes, as formulated. If you want to have a single query, you'd need to use joins. For that, I'd recommend using esqueleto.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
questions <- runDB $ selectList [QuestionTitle !=. ""] [LimitTo 10]
let askerIds = map (\(Entity _ q) -> questionAsker q) questions
askers <- runDB $ selectList [UserId <-. askerIds] []
let questionsAndAskers = zip questions askers
```

That seems like it should hit the DB once for the users.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the second line could be written `let askersIds = map (questionAsker . entityVal) questions` which I find more readable.