# How to use runDB correctly in Yesod / Persistent

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

I have the following persistent model:

```
User
    ident Text
    password Text Maybe
     UniqueUser ident
    deriving Typeable

Payment
    timestamp UTCTime
    from UserId
    to UserId
    amount Int
```

I am trying to build a page that displays a list of all payments in the database, with for each payment links to the users that paid / received the payment. Currently my code for this is:

```
getPaymentsR :: Handler Html
getPaymentsR = do
    let payments = map addFromTo $ runDB $ selectList [] [Desc PaymentTimestamp]
    defaultLayout
        [whamlet|
            <h3> Payments
            <ul>
                $forall (key, value, from, to) <- payments
                    <li>
                        <a href=@{UserR $ paymentFrom value}> #{from} </a> paid #{paymentAmount value} to <a href=@{UserR $ paymentTo value}> #{to} </a> on #{printDay $ paymentTimestamp value}
            $if null payments
                <ul>
                    <li> No payments
        |]
    where 
        addFromTo :: Entity Payment -> (Key Payment, Payment, Text, Text)
        addFromTo (Entity key val) = do
            let from = runDB $ get404 $ paymentFrom val
            let to = runDB $ get404 $ paymentTo val
            (key, val, userIdent from, userIdent to)
```

However I am getting the following errors:

```
Handler/Payment.hs:9:36:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Entity Payment]'
                with actual type `HandlerT site0 IO [Entity Payment]'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `runDB $ selectList [] [Desc PaymentTimestamp]'
    In the expression:
      map addFromTo $ runDB $ selectList [] [Desc PaymentTimestamp]
    In an equation for `payments':
        payments
          = map addFromTo $ runDB $ selectList [] [Desc PaymentTimestamp]

Handler/Payment.hs:26:34:
    Couldn't match expected type `User'
                with actual type `HandlerT site0 IO User'
    In the first argument of `userIdent', namely `from'
    In the expression: userIdent from
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: (key, val, userIdent from, userIdent to)

Handler/Payment.hs:26:50:
    Couldn't match expected type `User'
                with actual type `HandlerT site1 IO User'
    In the first argument of `userIdent', namely `to'
    In the expression: userIdent to
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: (key, val, userIdent from, userIdent to)
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong, or how to solve these errors?
I believe it has a lot to do with [Extracting database field values inside a Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891488/extracting-database-field-values-inside-a-handler).
However I was still unable to resolve the problem with the information in above link.

**Update**

After editing my code using Michael Snoyman's answer, my new addFromTo function is still giving type errors:

```
addFromTo :: Entity Payment -> (Key Payment, Payment, Text, Text)
addFromTo (Entity key val) = do
    from' <- runDB $ get404 $ paymentFrom val
    to' <- runDB $ get404 $ paymentTo val
    let from = userIdent from'
    let to = userIdent to'
    (key, val, from, to)
```

Comment: Looks like you are using map for Monadic values. Can you try `payments <- mapM addFromTo $ runDB $ selectList [] [Desc PaymentTimestamp]`

Comment: Unfortunately this resulted only in more errors.

Comment: this method didn't work for me too. but [another method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9389550/1838505) did it.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you're treating a monadic action as a pure value. The easier way to resolve this is to use do-notation and the slurp operator:

```
payments' <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc PaymentTimestamp]
let payments = map addFromTo payments'
```

Or if you want to get fancier (not necessarily recommended):

```
payments <- fmap (map addFromTo) $ runDB $ selectList [] [Desc PaymentTimestamp]
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works perfect for retrieving the list of payments. So if I understand correctly, the slurp operator extracts the pure value contained in the monad, after which 'regular' functions can be applied to the value. However if I try to apply this reasoning to my addFromTo function, I still get HandlerT type mismatches. Maybe I am getting these errors in addFromTo because of a different reason? I put my new addFromTo function in my original question.