# How to combine "details" from a separate query in a list in Hamlet?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, hamlet

I'd like to display a list of items in a webpage, along with associated details from a separate table (with a many-to-one relationship). How do I do this in Yesod? I am using the default scaffolding. The upshot is that `runDB` cannot be nested in a `WidgetT` context — or so I think.

To make this more concrete, how do I define the function `featuresAssociatedWith` to use in the following hamlet code:

```html
<h2> Cars

$forall Entity carId car <- carList
    <div class="car-item">
        <h3> #{carYear car}&nbsp;#{carMake car} #{carModel car}
        <ul>
            $forall feature <- featuresAssociatedWith carId
                <li> #{feature}
```

Given the following models:

```
Car
    make        Text
    model       Text
    year        Int

CarFeature
    car         CarId
    text        Text
    UniqueCF    car text
```

Here is the current handler function

```hs
getCarListR :: Handler Html
getCarListR = do
        carList <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CarOrder]
        liftIO $ print $ length carList
        defaultLayout $ do
            setTitle "Cars"
            $(widgetFile "carList")
```

It seems most natural to embed a `runDB` query in the Widget this way, but again, this isn't possible:

```hs
featuresAssocWith :: CarId -> [Entity CarFeature]
featuresAssocWith carID = selectList [CarFeatureCar ==. carID] []
```

Answer (score 2):

Hamlet is designed to not allow you to perform actions like database queries inside of it. Instead, you'll need to perform the query outside of hamlet, and then pass in a list of tuples of car info together with the data from the associated table.

Comment: While I respect keeping db lookups out of hamlet code, I find it odd that it would be restricted from occurring in widgets at all. Aside from that, I was just wondering if there's a "magical" way to do this in "Yesod" or "persistent". I'll end up doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9389550/712526) for now.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I didn't say you can't do it in a Widget, just not inside Hamlet. You can use [handlerToWidget](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.2.19.2/docs/Yesod-Core-Widget.html#v:handlerToWidget) to convert any Handler action into a Widget action.